# Slider/wizard that leads to a certain page based on choices made

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am currently developing a website(related to fitness) client wants to make a feature, that will allow user to select a workout plan based on the choices you pick from a slider similar to the one on [this example](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/).

What i'm trying to figure out if  this can be done with CSS or would I need to implement JavaScript / jQuery ?

Any help with this problem is appreciated. I just need a nudge in the right direction of where to start.

Edit: i have found [jQuery-Smart-Wizard](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/) that partially does what i want would i be able to manipulate this to have choices and load a certain page depending on the choice made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is design-related, as in colors, sizes, and layout. If you want conditional navigation, and to parse form data, you'll need to use jQuery/JavaScript to manipulate client side (optional), and some sort of server-side language such as PHP to manipulate the data and information.